# Regular expression for three or more consecutive letters of the alphabet

Tags: regex, match, alphabetical, alphabet

I want to write a regular expression that will find instances of three or more consecutive letters of the alphabet. I'm planning to use this regex with both JavaScript and `grep`. This seems like something that regex should be able to do pretty easily, but I'm having a hard time coming up with a regex that isn't very complicated:

`(abc(d(e(f(g(h(i(j(k(l(m(n(o(p(q(r(s(t(u(v(w(x(yz?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)|(bcd(e(f(g(h(i(j(k(l(m(n(o(p(q(r(s(t(u(v(w(x(yz?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)|(cde(f(g(h(i(j(k(l(m(n(o(p(q(r(s(t(u(v(w(x(yz?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)|...`

To be clear, I want to match these test cases:

- `abc` - match `abc`
- `def` - match `def`
- `lmnop` - match `lmnop`
- `xxxxghixxxx` - match `ghi`
- `ab` - no match (not long enough)
- `zyx` - no match (not in order)
- `q r s` - no match (interceding chararacters)
- `tuwx` - no match (missing `v`)

Is there a way to write this regex that doesn't use 20+ levels of nested parenthesis and 20+ `|`s?

Comment: You still need to spell out these possibilities. Besides, if the code works and you only think of enhancing it, please consider posting at [codereview.se].

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My code doesn't work, because it is too much to actually write out.  I only got three `|`s in before giving up because it is getting too complicated.

Answer (score 4):

This can be shortened to:

```
(?:(?=ab|bc|cd|de|ef|fg|gh|hi|ij|jk|kl|lm|mn|no|op|pq|qr|rs|st|tu|uv|vw|wx|xy|yz).){2,}.
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MPujo4/1)

---

- `(?:` - Open a non-capture group;

  - `(?=ab|bc|cd...).` - A nested positive lookahead to assert character after lookahead has it's correct successor;
- `){2,}` - Close non-capture group and match 2+ times;
- `.` - Match the final character to conclude the substring.

Comment: I like how easy it is to vary the required match length. If you want to match `n` consecutive characters, you use `n-1` in the curly braces.  For example to match 8 consecutive letters you use `{7,}`